# mechanize can't login python

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm making auto-login script by use mechanize python.

Before I was used mechanize with no problem, but `www.gmarket.co.kr` in this site I couldn't make it .

whenever i try to login always login page was returned even with correct gmarket id , pass, i can't login and I saw some suspicious message

```
"<script language=javascript>top.location.reload();</script>"
```

I think this related with my problem, but don't know exactly how to handle .
Here is sample id and pass for login test

id: tgi177     pass: tk1047

if anyone can help me much appreciate thanks in advance

CODE:

```
# -*- coding: cp949 -*-
from lxml.html import parse, fromstring
import sys,os
import mechanize, urllib
import cookielib
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup,BeautifulStoneSoup,Tag

try:

    params = urllib.urlencode({'command':'login',
                               'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmarket.co.kr%2F',
                               'member_type':'mem',
                               'member_yn':'Y',
                               'login_id':'tgi177',
                               'image1.x':'31',
                               'image1.y':'26',
                               'passwd':'tk1047',
                               'buyer_nm':'',
                               'buyer_tel_no1':'',
                               'buyer_tel_no2':'',
                               'buyer_tel_no3':''

                               })
    rq = mechanize.Request("http://www.gmarket.co.kr/challenge/login.asp")
    rs = mechanize.urlopen(rq)
    data = rs.read()    


    logged_in = r'input_login_check_value'  in data                                    
    if logged_in:
        print ' login success !'  
        rq = mechanize.Request("http://www.gmarket.co.kr") 
        rs = mechanize.urlopen(rq)
        data = rs.read()   
        print data  

    else:
        print 'login failed!'
        pass
        quit()      
except:
    pass
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a minimal example of the code that doesn't work so others can start with that as a basis.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply! 
i was upload my script in here
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/151607/
if any help much appreciate

Comment: A very experienced SO user asked you just two weeks ago to avoid using external [pastebin] services.  Please paste the relevant part of the code right into your post.  This way things stay in one place, your code is guaranteed to be still available as long as SO exists and people are bothered less => higher chance of answers.

Comment: A few things:

1) your example code imports third-party modules that it doesn't need so you'll likely get fewer responses than you otherwise would.

2) You don't do anything with params after building it...

3) I tried the user/pass on the site in Firefox and couldn't log in (as far as I could tell, I don't read Korean).

Comment: thanks paprika...you are right.
hello Benji York, i just tested with http://www.gmarket.co.kr/challenge/login.asp this page..and no problem with login with id:tgi177   pass: tk1047 and also sure i was test login with firefox 3.0 thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mechanize` doesn't have the ability to interact with JavaScript. Probably [`spidermonkey`](http://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey) module will help you (I have no experience with it, but description is quite promising). Also you could handle such reload (e.g.`Browser.reload()` for this particular case) manually if it's the only site you have this problem.

**Update**:
Quick look through your page shows that you have submit to other URL (with https: scheme). Look through `checkValid()` JavaScript function. Posting to it gives other result. Note, that this looks like homework you should do yourself before asking.

Comment: thanks for your reply...but problem is i have no idea how to handle javascript or other ..

Comment: I think the best way is to create `Browser` object and use its `reload()` method.